# Why does Stewie hate Lois?

Tags: family-guy

In the Family Guy, why does Stewie Griffin hate Lois so much? Why does he want to kill her?

Is there an episode in which this is explained?

Comment: Basically, as he says sometimes, in somewhat similar words: _She has impeded my progress ever since I emerged from her wretched womb._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate a little bit on what I said, Stewie is a megalomaniac who wishes to conquer the world. (At the first seasons, he later changes a lot)

He sees Lois as his bigger threat as she brought him into the world but gets really frustrated because he still needs her to take care of him even though he sees that as an insult.

Plus, what I've said in the comments: **She has impeded his progress ever since he emerged from her wretched womb**.